# merge "fasting" and "fast-days" tags?

Tags: discussion, specific-tag

[fast-days](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fast-days) has 41 questions; [fasting](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fasting) has three.  The three don't seem fundamentally different; they are not, for example, about tips for overcoming the physical difficulties of a fast.  (There's one of those in [fast-days](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fast-days), by the way.)

Is there any reason these tags shouldn't be merged?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've taken the liberty of effecting this. If they *should* be distinct, questions were mistagged anyway, so someone would need to go through them all anyway: thus, there was no harm in merging.

Answer (score 1):

I actually noticed this two days ago, and was considering asking it, but decided not to.

I did not check to see what long of questions were in each tag, admittedly, but I didn't ask because I felt that 'fasting' could be a more general tag for two reasons:

One, as you said, for general questions on fasting methods, and two, for non-public fast days.

Just my two cents, and not really relevant anymore, now that msh210 has merges them.

Comment: I wouldn't object to having two tags as you described them, but the distribution of questions between the tags didn't support that interpretation either, so it would have been necessary to move questions around.  So one for now and if we want to split it out later we can works for me.